# Angularjs, how to save selected items

Tags: angularjs

I would like to ask, how to remember selected answers in Angularjs, this is my project (it takes about 2s. to load questions and answers): http://testtest.ueuo.com/, so later on, I could count the final score and users can review the questions before submitting. There can be more than one correct answer.

This is for answers in index.html:

```
  </div>
       <div ng-repeat="answer in answers track by $index" ng-if="answer != ''"  class="{{selected}}" ng-click="addToAnswers(currentPage,$index)" >
   {{answer}}
         </div>
  </div>
```

this is in controller:

```
 $scope.addToAnswers = function(questionID ,$index) {
        if(this.selected == 'selected')this.selected = false;
        else this.selected = 'selected';
        console.log("Index clicked " + $index + " id: " + questionID + " selected: " + this.selected);
    }
```

I color selected answers by .selected in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>the `$index` every time starts from 0 so each time you select the index remains 0, 1, 2 , in consequence your class stays as selected ( angular won't understand that the element has changed ). use `track by answer.id` so it will change on every page.</del>

When you push on your user_answers model don't use index of `$index`

the way I would do it actually is make `user_answers` an object and each answer by user add a property with the question id as key and the answer as value.

so each time you have a model like this:

```
ng-model="user_answers[question.id]" ng-class="{selected: user_answers[question.id].id == answer.id }"
```

or something like that.

In your case, where you don't use the `ng-model` directive, you probably want to do the following, you also have to create a $scope variable for the question's id to use it on the `ngClick` as below:

```
$scope.user_answers = {};
$scope.addToAnswers = function(questionID, answer) {
    $scope.user_answers[questionID] = answer;
}
```

and in the view

```
ng-click="addToAnswers(questionId, answer)" ng-class="{selected: user_answers[question.id] == answer }"
```

#### UPDATE

For multiple correct answers, the answers in a specific question must be hold in an array:

```
$scope.toggleAnswers = function(questionID, answer) {
  if (angular.isUndefined($scope.user_answers[questionID])) {
    $scope.user_answers[questionID] = [];
  }
  if ($scope.checkSelected(questionID, answer)) {
    var i = $scope.user_answers[questionID].indexOf(answer)
    $scope.user_answers[questionID].splice(i,1);
  } else {
    $scope.user_answers[questionID].push(answer);
  }
  //$scope.localStorage.setItem('answers', angular.toJson(answers));
}
```

and the check if an answer has been checked:

```
$scope.checkSelected = function(questionId, answer) {
  if (angular.isUndefined($scope.user_answers[questionId])) { 
    return false;
  }
  return $scope.user_answers[questionId].indexOf(answer) !== -1;
}
```

Now `checkSelected` can be used in the `ngClass` also:

```
ng-class="{selected: checkSelected(CurrentQuestionId, answer)}"
```

*PS. imo the validation and the correct answers must reside on the server, otherwise someone can cheat.*

Comment: @thinkmore If you want to ask clarifying questions; do so; but comments aren't for an extended debug session or separate help. To do that get a chatroom.

Answer (score 0):

If it's anything close to a SPA, you can extend your controller and the `addToAnswers` function like this:

```
$scope.answers = [];

$scope.addToAnswers = function(questionID ,$index) {
    $scope.answers.push({index: $index, id: questionID});
}
```

This will add an item to the `answers` array, storing the index and the question id.

Comment: I want ,for example if I choose first answer, then i press next, on second question nothing should be selected and if I go back, the answer selected in first question should be green.